# Facebook shares not using og:url when clicked in Facebook?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

One of the purposes of og:url -- I thought -- was that it was a way you could make sure sessions variables, or any other personal information that might find its way into a URL, would not be passed along by sharing in places like Facebook. According to the best practices on Facebook's developer pages: "URL
A URL with no session id or extraneous parameters. All shares on Facebook will use this as the identifying URL for this article."
(under good examples: developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices)

This does NOT appear to be working, and I am puzzled as to either -- how I misunderstood, and/or what I have wrong in my code. Here's an example:
https://vault.sierraclub.org/fb/test.html?name=adrian

When I drop things into the debugger, it seems to be working fine... 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fvault.sierraclub.org%2Ffb%2Ftest.html%3Fname%3Dadrian

og:url reads as expected (without name=adrian).

**But if I share this on facebook** -- and then click the link. The URL goes to the one with name=adrian in it, not the og:url.

Am I doing something incorrectly here, or have I misunderstood? If the latter, how does one keep things like sessions variables out of shares?

Thanks for any insight.

#### UPDATE

Facebook replied to a bug report on this, and I learned that I indeed was reading the documentation incorrectly
developers.facebook.com/bugs/178234669405574/

**The question then remains** -- is there any other method to keeping sessions variables/authentication tokens out of shares?

Comment: why would you use a get parameter on a html page?

Comment: anyway, you are sharing the url with the parameter, so of course it goes exactly to the shared url.

Comment: That is not what should happen according to Facebook (see documentation linked above). The link in facebook should be the og:url.

There are many reasons to use get parameters on an html page. The fact that it is .html is just a test. But in a real use case of this, it is links from emails that subsequently get shared on social media which contain session or user information. The session information is used by the backend to prefill information. This is usually a one-time use, but people often share things before they've actually done it.

Comment: Having reached out to Facebook -- I have learned that my reading of the documentation was incorrect. They want sessions values stripped so they can get the generic page, but they otherwise pass along the parameters to the user.